# Which multidimensional data storage to use?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a project I'm working on in which I need to have first, an infinite 2d array of integers (probably somewhat small) each of these containing another 2d array 100x100, in each of those, another array, 100x100, and in each of those, a 3d array array 10x10x2000 and finally, each of these would need to have a string,string dictionary. I have no idea how hard this would be on the memory and performance, and I tried to make a class for each dictionary:

EDIT: I got a working system so far but it is still really slow.

```
public class individual {
public Dictionary<string,object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
public individual() {
    data.Add ("Type","None");
}
public object get (string Attr) {
    if (data.ContainsKey(Attr)) {
        return data[Attr];
    } else {
        return "None";
    }
}
public void set (string key,object setter) {
    if (data.ContainsKey(key)) {
        data[key] = setter;
    }else{
        data.Add(key,setter);
    }
}
```

Then I tried putting them all in an array, but there were always errors when I initialized the sub arrays:

```
object[][,][,][,][,,] alldata = new object[1][,][,][,][,,];
```

And then:

```
alldata[0] =new object[100,100][,][,][,,];
    alldata[0][1,1] = new object[100,100][,][,,];
    alldata[0][1,1][1,1] =new object[100,100][,,];
    alldata[0][1,1][1,1][1,1] =new object[100,100,100];
    alldata[0][1,1][1,1][1,1][1,1,1] = new individual();
    individual test = (individual)alldata[0][1,1][1,1][1,1][1,1,1];
```

Any advice as to how I should store the data, or if it's even possible?

Comment: Array indexes start at 0. See [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx). However, whatever you're trying to accomplish with this, there *has* to be a better way.

Comment: An infinite 2d array of integers is typically rather heavy on memory, even if they're somewhat small integers.

Comment: It's hard to give good advice without knowing more about your project, but there might be a better data structure to represent what you're trying to model.  Unless you know you're going to populate every index, initializing every array will needlessly take up more memory than you need to use.

Comment: The first 2d arrays containing everything else could be initialized as I need them, but everything inside should all come as soon as I initialize (or call a special function initializing) it.

Comment: @p.s.w.g That was what was making my code throw the errors. Now It works, but seems slow... any suggestions to optimize?

Comment: @DiodeII It's impossible to know without a *lot* more context. Once you get your code working, you might try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Aha! I had one more array index than I needed and now thing work normally again! only 2 seconds to load.

Comment: I think you need to consider another data structure, second when you initialize your array you need to specify the dimensions that you need or pass the elements instead.